# Batch macro displaying date and time followed by text

Tags: batch-file, macros

What I have done so far (displays both date and time on a WIN2K3 5.2.3790 machine with a leading space) :

```
SET DATETIME=(FOR /F %%C IN ('TIME/T') DO SET /P NOW=%%C : )&(FOR /F "TOKENS=2 DELIMS= " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET /P NOW=%NOW% %%A <NUL)

%DATETIME%
```

I want to remove the leading space before the date that the set /p adds and add parameter for text but can't find a solution. I would also like to add a parameter for text as described here http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-macros.html once the set /p gets solved.

What I would like to get as a result (but with a batch macro instead of a call) :

```
@ECHO OFF

CALL :DATETIME "HELLO WORLD "
PAUSE>NUL

:DATETIME
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO FOR %%B IN (%%A) DO SET NOW=%%B
FOR /F %%C IN ('TIME/T') DO SET /P NOW=%NOW% %%C %~1< NUL
```

Thank you,

Comment: if you join a command with an ampersand you build a codeblock and can't access this `%variables%`. You need `delayed expansion` and `!variables!` .

Answer (score 1):

I get the impression that the task is to echo a date and time and text on the same line:

echo %date% @ %time% - "Hello World"

Comment: Yes, it seems so. A macro is a little bit too complex for this

Answer (score 0):

As you referenced the macros at ss64.com you should try to use the syntax shown there.

It's not necessary but a good way to use the `%\n%` formatting.

```
@ECHO OFF
set LF=^


::Above 2 blank lines are required - do not remove
set ^"\n=^^^%LF%%LF%^%LF%%LF%^^"
SET DATETIME=( %\n%
  FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO ( %\n%
    FOR /F %%C IN ('TIME/T') DO SET /P "NOW=%%A%%C "^<NUL%\n%
  )%\n%
)

set datet
echo ------
%DATETIME% 
echo Hello World
```